# How can I test a change made to Jenkinsfile locally?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

When writing jenkins pipelines it seems to be very inconvenient to commit each new change in order to see if it works.

Is there a way to execute these locally without committing the code?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You cannot execute a Pipeline script locally, since its whole purpose is to script Jenkins. (Which is one reason why it is best to keep your `Jenkinsfile` short and limited to code which actually deals with Jenkins features; your actual build logic should be handled with external processes or build tools which you invoke via a one-line `sh` or `bat` step.)

If you want to test a change to `Jenkinsfile` live but without *committing* it, use [the **Replay** feature](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/replay-pipeline) added in 1.14.

[JENKINS-33925](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33925) tracks the feature request for an automated test framework.

Comment: The blog post says there's a 'replay' button. Any idea where? I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain, go to the Jenkins page of your build job. On the left side you should see the list of previous build runs. When you hover over a build run ID (e.g. "#123") or a date of a build run, a little down arrow appears. Clicking on it reveals a context menu which has the option "Replay". The option is also available on the page of a build run.

Comment: Concourse allows you to execute your local scripts against a target build server, so you can validate it will actually work on the remote server too before committing your changes. https://concourse.ci/fly-cli.html.  The Jenkins replay feature is somewhat analogous to this except it has limitations and you have to create a build first in order to replay it.

Comment: You could have a look to [this project](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner) that aim at providing what you are looking for.

Comment: Or, better than `sh` or `bat`, use a multi-platform language like `python`.  Now you can (probably) interchange Windows and Linux nodes.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to run most of our scripts outside of jenkins, in order to try and debug them much more easily. But, how could we use the Jenkins pipeline utility functions (like readMavenPom and writeMavenPom)?

Comment: Take a look at JenkinsPipelineUnit (https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit)

Comment: I think what would make sense is if you could still run the pipeline code from within Jenkins but pointing it to the local version of the Jenkinsfile. Then you could run it from local to check it works, then push the change if it does.

Comment: @Mig82 there is a `replay-pipeline` CLI command for that purpose.

Answer (score 129):

I have a solution that works well for me. It consists of a local jenkins running in docker and a git web hook to trigger the pipeline in the local jenkins on every commit. You no longer need to push to your github or bitbucket repository to test the pipeline.

*This has only been tested in a linux environment.*

It is fairly simple to make this work although this instruction is a tad long. Most steps are there.

## This is what you need

- [Docker installed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) and working. *This is not part of this instruction.*
- A Jenkins running in docker locally. *Explained how below.*

  - The proper rights (ssh access key) for your local Jenkins docker user to pull from your local git repo.  *Explained how below.*
  - A Jenkins pipeline project that pulls from your local git repository. *Explained below.*
  - A git user in your local Jenkins with minimal rights. *Explained below.*
- A git project with a post-commit web hook that triggers the pipeline project. *Explained below.*

## This is how you do it

### Jenkins Docker

Create a file called Dockerfile in place of your choosing. I'm placing it in `/opt/docker/jenkins/Dockerfile` fill it with this:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
# Your needed installations goes here
USER jenkins
```

**Build the local_jenkins image**

This you will need to do only once or after you have added something to the Dockerfile.

```
$ docker build -t local_jenkins /opt/docker/jenkins/
```

**Start and restart local_jenkins**

From time to time you want to start and restart jenkins easily. E.g. after a reboot of your machine. For this I made an alias that I put in `.bash_aliases` in my home folder.

```
$ echo "alias localjenkinsrestart='docker stop jenkins;docker rm jenkins;docker run --name jenkins -i -d -p 8787:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /opt/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:rw local_jenkins'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
$ source .bash_aliases  # To make it work
```

*Make sure the `/opt/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home` folder exists and that you have user read and write rights to it.*

To start or restart your jenkins just type:

```
$ localjenkinsrestart
```

*Everything you do in your local jenkins will be stored in the folder /opt/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home and preserved between restarts.*

**Create a ssh access key in your docker jenkins**

This is a very important part for this to work. First we start the docker container and create a bash shell to it:

```
$ localjenkinsrestart
$ docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash
```

*You have now entered into the docker container, this you can see by something like `jenkins@e7b23bad10aa:/$` in your terminal. The hash after the @ will for sure differ.*

Create the key

```
jenkins@e7b23bad10aa:/$ ssh-keygen
```

*Press enter on all questions until you get the prompt back*

Copy the key to your computer. From within the docker container your computer is 172.17.0.1 should you wonder.

```
jenkins@e7b23bad10aa:/$ ssh-copy-id user@172.17.0.1
```

*user = your username and 172.17.0.1 is the ip address to your computer from within the docker container.*

You will have to type your password at this point.

Now lets try to complete the loop by ssh-ing to your computer from within the docker container.

```
jenkins@e7b23bad10aa:/$ ssh user@172.17.0.1
```

*This time you should not need to enter you password. If you do, something went wrong and you have to try again.*

You will now be in your computers home folder. Try `ls` and have a look.

**Do not stop here since we have a chain of ssh shells that we need to get out of.**

```
$ exit
jenkins@e7b23bad10aa:/$ exit
```

Right! Now we are back and ready to continue.

**Install your Jenkins**

You will find your local Jenkins in your browser at http://localhost:8787.

First time you point your browser to your local Jenkins your will be greated with a Installation Wizard. 
Defaults are fine, do make sure you install the pipeline plugin during the setup though.

**Setup your jenkins**

It is **very important** that you activate matrix based security on [http://localhost:8787/configureSecurity](http://localhost:8787/configureSecurity/) and **give yourself all rights** by adding yourself to the matrix and tick all the boxes. *(There is a tick-all-boxes icon on the far right)*

- Select `Jenkins’ own user database` as the Security Realm
- Select `Matrix-based security` in the Authorization section
- Write your username in the field `User/group to add:` and click on the `[ Add ]` button
- In the table above your username should pop up with a people icon next to it. *If it is crossed over you typed your username incorrectly.*
- Go to the far right of the table and click on the tick-all-button or manually tick all the boxes in your row.
- Please verify that the checkbox `Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits` is unchecked. *(Since this Jenkins is only reachable from your computer this isn't such a big deal)*
- Click on `[ Save ]` and log out of Jenkins and in again just to make sure it works. 
  *If it doesn't you have to start over from the beginning and emptying the `/opt/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home` folder before restarting*

**Add the git user**

We need to allow our git hook to login to our local Jenkins with minimal rights. Just to see and build jobs is sufficient. Therefore we create a user called `git` with password `login`.

Direct your browser to http://localhost:8787/securityRealm/addUser and add `git` as username and `login` as password. 
Click on `[ Create User ]`.

**Add the rights to the git user**

Go to the [http://localhost:8787/configureSecurity](http://localhost:8787/configureSecurity/) page in your browser. Add the git user to the matrix:

- Write `git` in the field `User/group to add:` and click on `[ Add ]`

Now it is time to check the boxes for minimal rights to the git user. Only these are needed:

- overall:read
- job:build
- job:discover
- job:read

Make sure that the `Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits` checkbox is unchecked and click on `[ Save ]`

### Create the pipeline project

We assume we have the username `user` and our git enabled project with the `Jenkinsfile` in it is called `project` and is located at `/home/user/projects/project`

In your http://localhost:8787 Jenkins add a new pipeline project. I named it hookpipeline for reference.

- Click on `New Item` in the Jenkins menu
- Name the project `hookpipeline`
- Click on Pipeline
- Click `[ OK ]`
- Tick the checkbox `Poll SCM` in the Build Triggers section. Leave the Schedule empty.
- In the Pipeline section:

  - select `Pipeline script from SCM`
  - in the `Repository URL` field enter `user@172.17.0.1:projects/project/.git`
  - in the `Script Path` field enter `Jenkinsfile`
- Save the hookpipeline project
- Build the hookpipeline manually once, this is needed for the Poll SCM to start working.

### Create the git hook

Go to the `/home/user/projects/project/.git/hooks` folder and create a file called `post-commit` that contains this:

```
#!/bin/sh
BRANCHNAME=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
MASTERBRANCH='master'

curl -XPOST -u git:login http://localhost:8787/job/hookpipeline/build
echo "Build triggered successfully on branch: $BRANCHNAME"
```

Make this file executable:

```
$ chmod +x /home/user/projects/project/.git/hooks/post-commit
```

Test the post-commit hook:

```
$ /home/user/projects/project/.git/hooks/post-commit
```

Check in Jenkins if your hookpipeline project was triggered.

Finally make some arbitrary change to your project, add the changes and do a commit. This will now trigger the pipeline in your local Jenkins.

Happy Days!

Comment: I had to replace `docker build -t local_jenkins /opt/docker/jenkins/Dockerfile` with `docker build -t local_jenkins /opt/docker/jenkins` because Docker complained about "unable to prepare context: context must be a directory".

Comment: I'm getting this error in Mac. Can someone please help me on this? >> ERROR: ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.1 port 22: Connection refused –

Comment: @ManojShrestha: The ip 172.17.0.1 is the default ip to the machine that is running the docker containers. You can use your machines (MAC:s) ip instead.

Comment: @ManojShrestha: You can also try to find out the gateway ip of your setup like this:
    
    `$ docker inspect jenkins | grep Gateway`

Comment: If your docker host is installed on macOS and you wish to ssh login to it from within the docker container then you should

`ssh user@docker.for.mac.localhost`

instead of using the IP address.

Also make sure you enabled the Remote Login feature from the macOs System Preferences -> Shared Folder menu

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed guide, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note: The post-commit CURL command has changed for newer versions of Jenkins. Use `curl -v -XPOST -u git:$API_TOKEN http://localhost:8787/job/VMInit/build` after retrieving an API Token value from the UI via your user's config page (Top right corner. See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/authenticating-scripted-clients/)

Comment: 3 years later these instructions are a little off, but work wonderfully. Tip for those that discover that the container is running as user Jenkins and you want to adjust /etc/hosts without root: Just `docker exec -u 0 -it jenkins /bin/bash` and you're root! Do bad things!

Answer (score 76):

**TL;DR**

- [Jenkins Pipeline Unit testing framework](https://github.com/lesfurets/JenkinsPipelineUnit)
- [Jenkinsfile Runner](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner)

**Long Version**
Jenkins Pipeline testing becomes more and more of a pain. Unlike the *classic* declarative job configuration approach where the user was limited to what the UI exposed the new Jenkins Pipeline is a full fledged programming language for the build process where you mix the declarative part with your own code. As good developers we want to have some unit tests for this kind of code as well.

There are three steps you should follow when developing Jenkins Pipelines. The **step 1.** should cover 80% of the uses cases.

1. Do as much as possible in build scripts (eg. Maven, Gradle, Gulp etc.). Then in your pipeline scripts just calls the build tasks in the right order. The build pipeline just orchestrates and executes the build tasks but does not have any major logic that needs a special testing.
2. If the previous rule can't be fully applied then move over to [Pipeline Shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) where you can develop and test custom logic on its own and integrate them into the pipeline.
3. If all of the above fails you, you can try one of those libraries that came up recently (March-2017). [Jenkins Pipeline Unit testing framework](https://github.com/lesfurets/JenkinsPipelineUnit) or [pipelineUnit](https://github.com/macg33zr/pipelineUnit) (examples). Since 2018 there is also [Jenkinsfile Runner](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner), a  package to execution Jenkins pipelines from a command line tool.

**Examples**

The [pipelineUnit](https://github.com/macg33zr/pipelineUnit) GitHub repo contains some Spock examples on how to use [Jenkins Pipeline Unit testing framework](https://github.com/lesfurets/JenkinsPipelineUnit)

Comment: Can you also include a brief comparison of those two libraries?

Answer (score 32):

Jenkins has a 'Replay' feature, which enables you to quickly replay a job without updating sources:

[image: Replay feature]

Comment: Note that it shows up on the build page, not the project or branch page.

Answer (score 23):

At the moment of writing **(end of July 2017)** with the [Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/) plugin you can check the syntax of a declarative pipeline directly in the **visual pipeline editor**. The editor, works from the Blue Ocean UI when you click "configure" only for **github projects** (this is a known issue and they are working to make it work also on git etc).

But, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371212/where-is-the-blue-ocean-pipeline-editor) you can open the editor browsing to:

`[Jenkins URL]/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/`

Then click in the middle of the page, and press `Ctrl+S`, this will open a textarea where you can paste a pipeline declarative script. When you click on *Update*, if there is a syntax error, the editor will let you know where the syntax error is. Like in this screenshot:

[image: As a quick test I wrongly typed "stepps" instead of "steps"]

If there is no syntax error, the textarea will close and the page will visualize your pipeline. Don't worry it won't save anything (if it's a github project it would commit the Jenkinsfile change).

I'm new to Jenkins and this is quite helpful, without this I had to commit a Jenkinsfile many times, till it works (very annoying!). Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: That's because as of 2017, Jenkins is still aimed on addressing point-and-click software engineers problems ;) .... At least Atom has a decent Groovy linter. Is only Groovy but it helps.

Comment: The editor with syntax highlighting is also part of the classic jenkins UI.

Comment: Looks like this only works with declarative pipelines, not with scripted pipelines (groovy)

Answer (score 9):

A bit late to the party, but that's why I wrote `jenny`, a small reimplementation of some core Jenkinsfile steps. (https://github.com/bmustiata/jenny)

Comment: No offence, but unless you are constantly updating your stuff it will be pretty useless as the pipeline syntax is in a constant state of flux it seems at the moment.

Comment: Not taken. From what I've seen so far, the pipeline syntax, it's pretty much standardized for the basic pipeline steps (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/). I'm using it for ~2 years now, without running into any backwards incompatible changes. Jenkins plugins shouldn't be used imho, and the changing API can be abstracted using custom commands in shared libraries, where you'll have API guarantees.

If you're talking about the declarative syntax, that might be true. I use only the programmatic API in my pipelines, and that's what Jenny supports.

Rock solid :)

Answer (score 8):

In my development setup – missing a proper Groovy editor – a great deal of Jenkinsfile issues originates from simple *syntax errors*. To tackle this issue, you can validate the Jenkinsfile against your Jenkins instance (running at `$JENKINS_HTTP_URL`):

`curl -X POST -H $(curl '$JENKINS_HTTP_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)') -F "jenkinsfile=<Jenkinsfile" $JENKINS_HTTP_URL/pipeline-model-converter/validate`

The above command is a slightly modified version from 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Validating-(or-linting)-a-Declarative-Jenkinsfile-from-the-command-line

Comment: This  is just the sort of thing I was looking for - unfortunately it only works for *declarative* pipelines and not scripted pipelines :(

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know this [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) is the "Engine" of the new Jenkinsfile mechanics, so im quite positive you could use this to locally test your scripts.

Im not sure if there is any additional steps needed when you copy it into a Jenkinsfile, however the syntax etc should be exactly the same.

**Edit:** Found the reference on the "engine", check [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/2.0+Pipeline+as+Code) feature description, last paragraph, first entry.

Answer (score 4):

Using the VS Code [Jenkins Jack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tabeyti.jenkins-jack) extension, you can have a way to test your Jenkinsfiles without use the git push way, from your local files to a local or remote running Jenkins. And you will have the running log of the job inside VS Code, the ability to create jobs in Jenkins and more stuff. I hope this help to more people looking for a way to develop Jenkinsfiles.

Answer (score 3):

> For simplicity, you can create a Jenkinsfile at the root of the git repository, similar to the below example 'Jenkinsfile' based on the groovy syntax of the declarative pipeline.

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build the Project') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/jaikrgupta/CarthageAPI-1.0.git'
                echo pwd()
                sh 'ls -alrt'
                sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                sh 'python app.py &'
                echo "Build stage gets finished here"
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'chmod 777 ./scripts/test-script.sh'
                sh './scripts/test-script.sh'
                sh 'cat ./test-reports/test_script.log'
                echo "Test stage gets finished here"
            }
        }
}
```

https://github.com/jaikrgupta/CarthageAPI-1.0.git

> You can now set up a new item in Jenkins as a Pipeline job.
> Select the `Definition` as `Pipeline script from SCM` and `Git` for the `SCM` option.
> Paste the project's git repo link in the Repository URL and `Jenkinsfile` in the script name box.
> Then click on the `lightweight checkout` option and save the project.
> So whenever you pushed a commit to the git repo, you can always test the changes running the `Build Now` every time in Jenkins.

Please follow the instructions in the below visuals for easy setup a Jenkins Pipeline's job.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the Replay feature that others already mentioned (ditto on its usefulness!), I found the following to be useful as well:

1. Create a test Pipeline job where you can type in Pipeline code or point to your repo/branch of a Jenkinsfile to quickly test out something. For more accurate testing, use a Multibranch Pipeline that points to your own fork where you can quickly make changes and commit without affecting prod. Stuff like BRANCH_NAME env is only available in Multibranch.
2. Since Jenkinsfile is Groovy code, simply invoke it with "groovy Jenkinsfile" to validate basic syntax.

Comment: Using separate jobs that you can hide away and not confuse your users is one of the most important things. I edit the Jenkins files with IntelliJ. It is quite good at showing syntax faults. However, the reply button is the key thing. I create a branch with the basic  change run that - it usually goes a bit wrong. I then edit the Jenkinsfile and copy and paste that to the Replay window, and run again - I repeat this until it works OK and then commit the working version.

Answer (score 2):

Put your SSH key into your Jenkins profile, then use the [declarative linter](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/) as follows:

```
ssh jenkins.hostname.here declarative-linter < Jenkinsfile
```

This will do a static analysis on your Jenkinsfile. In the editor of your choice, define a keyboard shortcut that runs that command automatically. In Visual Studio Code, which is what I use, go to Tasks > Configure Tasks, then use the following JSON to create a *Validate Jenkinsfile* command:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Validate Jenkinsfile",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "ssh jenkins.hostname declarative-linter < ${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just validate your pipeline to find out syntax issues. Jenkins has nice API for [Jenkisfile validation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter) - *https://jenkins_url/pipeline-model-converter/validate*

Using curl and passing your .Jenkinsfile, you will get syntax check instantly

```
curl --user username:password -X POST -F "jenkinsfile=<jenkinsfile" https://jenkins_url/pipeline-model-converter/validate
```

You can add this workflow to editors:

- [VS Code](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/11/07/Validate-Jenkinsfile/)
- [Sublime Text](https://kraag22.com/articles/jenkins-develop-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

i am using replay future , to do some update and run quickly .

Comment: Can you please provide some more info on how you make this work?

Comment: I am using Bit-bucket as a source manager , then i have created a project on Jenkins wish discover my repository automatically, i recommend this post.    After each push on my repo Jenkins wil automatically play my Jenkins file and if it fail , on the left menu there is a button called Replay, ==> this button open an editor containing your Jenkins file  , you can edit it and replay the job ,

Answer (score 0):

With some limitations and for scripted pipelines I use this solution:

1. Pipeline job with an inlined groovy script:

---

```
node('master') {
    stage('Run!') {
                def script = load('...you job file...')
    }
}
```

---

2. Jenkinsfile for testing have same structure as for lesfurets:

---

```
def execute() {
 ... main job code here ...
}
execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a short solution that lets me test Pipeline code very quickly:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
        text(name: 'SCRIPT', defaultValue: params.SCRIPT,
            description: 'Groovy script')
    }
    stages {
        stage("main") {
            steps {
                script {
                    writeFile file: 'script.groovy', 
                        text: params.SCRIPT
                    def groovyScript = load 'script.groovy'
                    echo "Return value: " + groovyScript
                }
            } // steps
        } // stage
    } // stages
} // pipeline
```

1. `skipDefaultCheckout true` because we do not need the files in this tool git repository.
2. `defaultValue: params.SCRIPT` sets the default to the latest execution.  If used by just one user, it allows for a very quick cycle of short tests.
3. The given script is written to a file, and loaded and with `load`.

With this setup I can test **everything** I can do inside my other Jenkinsfiles, including using shared libraries.