# How can I test my jenkins ci pipelines locally?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am writing a number of ci scripts for jenkins pipelines.  A frequently occuring pattern is

```
dir("path/to/stuff"){
   do_stuff()
}
```

I would like to 'test-run' these scripts to achieve a (very) short feedback loop.  But I immediately run into the fact that this `dir` method is not an 'official' groovy method.

```
$ groovy ci/test-ci-scripts.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
  test-ci-scripts.dir() is applicable for argument types: ....
```

What do I need to import to get this running?

Comment: So far the only way I found is to start Jenkins locally, perhaps in a Docker container, and run it there. After all the point of pipelines is to be able to quickly set it up in any server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test a change made to Jenkinsfile locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309063/how-can-i-test-a-change-made-to-jenkinsfile-locally)

Answer (score -3):

just use single apostrophe's

```
dir('path') {
    // some block
}
```

works fine for me. (You can find `dir` in Jenkins Pipeline Snippet Generator)

Comment: and can you run `groovy my-ci-script.groovy` on your command line?

Comment: I'm really not sure, if this works, at least if a) steps out of the Jenkins DSL or b) calls to Jenkins Java API are made.