# Where is the Blue Ocean pipeline editor?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

Where is the pipeline editor located within the Blue Ocean Jenkins plugin?

I can see my pipeline jobs, and when clicking into these I cant see any links\buttons that take me to the editor.

I'm sure in previous beta releases I could get to it, but now since the official release has been launched which I am now using, I cannot find it.

Anyone know where it's hiding?

Answer (score 13):

Use following url to open the pipeline editor:
`http://<host>:<port>/jenkins/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/`

Comment: Thanks ! It is a strange UX to have to type the full url ^^

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Prashant Kajale's answer, you can edit a specific item with

```
[Url of Jenkins]/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/[item-name]
```

Edit: According to the issue tracker, saving doesn't work with none-github repositories. You have to go to `[Url of Jenkins]/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/` and open the load/save dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, paste you `Jenkinsfile` (if you have one yet), edit it, and then save it manually by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and copy.

Comment: Full support for editing Git-based repositories is coming soon. You can follow this issue for updates: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43148

Comment: @cliff.meyers Not sure if our definitions of "soon" match. The last commit in the repository has been done on 2017-03-25.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, is there another URL that offers this now?

Comment: It also doesn't work for me. I have a Jenkinsfile in a multi pipeline project called "foo", branch "master". I tried `[JenkinsURL]/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/foo` (I tried also `foo/master`): I get this error: `There was an error loading the pipeline from the Jenkinsfile in this repository. Correct the error by editing the Jenkinsfile using the declarative syntax then commit it back to the repository.`. With a valid Jenkinsfile (runs successfully)

@konstin can you be more specific what [item-name] should be or giving a more detailed (steps to reproduce) and working example?

Comment: @firepol: It's exactly what the error message says: You must use the declarative syntax in your Jenkinsfile, otherwise the pipeline editor can't be used.

Comment: @konstin: I am using a declarative syntax in my multi branch pipeline and it can build correctly. It's the pipeline editor that doesn't load anything... It's because I'm using a git server other than github and it's a known problem for now for the pipeline editor not to work on source code hosted elsewhere than github (e.g. we use gerrit, and you?). I was thinking that if I use the proper syntax for [item-name] I could load something... just maybe share an example if you have a branch called "foo/bar" (of just "master")

Comment: @firepol Ok, sorry then. Afaik the pipeline lacks a bunch of features for non-github projects, though I haven't thoroughly tested what works and what doesn't. You might find some helpful information in the tracking issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43148

Comment: I was able to edit the pipeline by going to this URL `[JenkinsURL]/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/[item-name]/[branch]` for v1.3.0 of Blue Ocean plugin

Answer (score 8):

It is hidden and does not show up until you hover over. I suppose simply a bad UI
 design.

1. Open Blue Ocean from a job.
2. Select a branch from Branches.
3. Hover over to the right and buttons will show up.
4. Select "Edit" and the editor will open.

[image]

Comment: every time I come back to using jenkins I struggle to find it, really poor design

Comment: Thanks. This is the simple answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug where the editor links do not display when the job is moved to a folder.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46441

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible reasons why the pipeline editor button isn't showing, either you're not logged in as a user or you're pipeline project is not into github repository.

Blue ocean doesn't support yet generating pipelines with **blueocean-pipeline-editor-plugin** when your SCM is bitbucket or gitlab or any other git tool.

The good news is that we will have editor support for Bitbucket and plain Git (which will include Gitlab) in our 1.3 release soon.

You can find more details about this issue [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45681)

Answer (score 0):

In the Blue Ocean pipeline view, there's a pencil icon on the upper right that lets you edit. So if you click an entry under the Activity tab, if you click any run of the job it will take you to this (green indicates a successful run):

[image: Blue ocean pipeline header]

An example URL for a pipeline named *my-pipeline* would be:

http://localhost:8080/blue/organizations/jenkins/my-pipeline/detail/jenkins/1/pipeline

Answer (score 0):

After installing Jenkins (either for Windows or Linux), you will need to install the plugin for Blue Ocean:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/getting-started/

**How To Use Blue Ocean and edit an existing pipeline**

After installing Blue Ocean and creating a small pipeline, you should be able to see this context menu:
[image]

Then, you will see your pipeline in a new "dashboard". Click on the row for the pipeline you need to work on:
[image]

You will get another "dashboard" looking screen. Editing is done from the configuration button (the gear icon) on the top menu:
[image]

This will take you to the Classic UI look, click on the Pipeline tab:
[image]

This is a complicated UI that either is designed to dissuade you not to use it or is in a desperate need for a redesign, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

as login to github use:

1. username (not email)
2. pat token with:
   a. repo access (i selected all)
   b. user:email

hope that helps