# How to test Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I am trying to write the test cases to validate the Jenkinsfile, But the load script function not working expecting the extension to be provided and throwing ResourceException exception `loadScript("Jenkinsfile")`

Is their better way to test the Jenkinsfile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test a change made to Jenkinsfile locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309063/how-can-i-test-a-change-made-to-jenkinsfile-locally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are not enough tools for the development of pipelines. Pipelines is DSL and it imposes a restrictions.

There is an interesting approach to using flags. For example, `test` which defines outside pipeline(in job). If `test=true`, a pipeline change some "production" logic to "test" - select another agent, load artifacts into another repository, run another command and so on.

But recently appeared [Pipeline Unit Testing Framework](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit). It allows  you to unit test Pipelines and Shared Libraries before running them in full. It provides a mock execution environment where real Pipeline steps are replaced with mock objects that you can use to check for expected behavior.

Useful links:

- [Jenkins World 2017: JenkinsPipelineUnit: Test your Continuous Delivery Pipeline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmrpUtbVR7o)
- [Pipeline Development Tools](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your Declarative Pipeline locally thanks to Jenkins built-in features.This can be done using a Jenkins CLI command or by making an HTTP POST request with appropriate parameters.

The command is the following:

```
curl -s -X POST -F "jenkinsfile=<YourJenkinsfile" \
https://user:password@jenkins.example.com/pipeline-model-converter/validate
```

For a practical example follow this guide:
https://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2020/10/validate-jenkinsfile.html